# Madam vs. Ma'am

Tags: word-usage, offensive-language, politeness

I suspect that the answer to this depends on region, so insights from multiple areas would be beneficial:

It has been my impression that in the US addressing a woman as "Madam" is considered borderline-vulgar due to the term's usage as the title of a female proprietor of a brothel.

Is it acceptable to use "Madam" when addressing a woman you do not know or should the alternative "Ma'am" (silent "D") be used?  Does it depend on spoken vs. written communication?

Comment: US usage may differ, but certainly in the UK I've never heard anyone suggest that the honorific "Madam" might give offense due to association with brothels. And the shortened "Ma'am" is considered acceptable when addressing the Queen (only after the first time, when you must say "Your Majesty"), so I'd say that's always okay *in speech*. But in writing it should always be "Madam", *never* "Ma'am".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's a good point about not writing "Ma'am."

Comment: As long as you don't use an article (**the** madam, or **a** madam) I can't imagine anyone taking offense.  Good:  "Allow me to introduce Madam Smith."  Bad: "Allow me to introduce the madam, Smith."

Comment: @MT_Head I've never heard anyone called 'Madam Smith' unless they happened to be French (Madame) or associated with arts such as ballet, opera etc. In everyday English usage you would not use Madam with a surname.

Comment: @Mynamite - Google is a thing.  Use it.

Comment: @MT_Head Is it helpful to be so rude? Google is comparatively young and can only base its stats on data it finds online. Unless you think it listens in to all conversations and reads all paperwork, current and historic? I stand by my original comment.

Comment: @Mynamite - Any general answer based on no more authority than "I've never heard..." automatically draws my scorn.  You're correct that this is not "everyday" usage, but it _is_ used, and not too uncommonly - as you would learn, if you could but Google the word "madam".  Madam Secretary, Madam President, Madam Stoltz, Madam Montessori...  In everyday American usage one would say "Mrs.", and in French one would say "Madame", but at American and English governmental or diplomatic events you'll most likely hear "Madam". As to what Google can base its stats on, check out http://books.google.com

Comment: @Mynamite - When I search for "Madam Smith" on Google Books, I find: ["When they were not entertaining guests themselves, Madam Smith and her children were often away from home..."](http://books.google.com/books?id=X_f-2jnxn2gC&pg=PA47&dq=madam+smith&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bgNWU-qjEoGOyATSwIKwDQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=madam%20smith&f=false)

Comment: @Mynamite - More to the point, see "Diplomatic Titles" at the end of [this guide](http://www.ediplomat.com/nd/protocol/communicating.htm).

Comment: @MT_Head Interesting links, though I cannot see how they bolster your argument. "Diplomatic titles" makes only one mention of Madam + surname, the rest are all Madam + Title (Madam President etc, which I have not disagreed with). Your other link goes to a diary from 1790's colonial America which also refers to 'negro wenches' - hardly something to recommend it as a model for modern usage. Scorn all you like, I'd rather use my own common sense and experience than go running to google for dubious evidence.

Comment: @Mynamite - Two minor points: first, "Diplomatic titles" makes two references, not one; second, that's not a link to a diary, but to a scholarly work about colonial life.  (I do concede that it's not a guide to modern life; I just found it amusing to combine Google Books with "Madam Smith".)  Finally, did you actually *read* my original comment - the one you jumped in to correct?  When was the last time, in "everyday" English usage, that you heard someone say "Allow me to introduce..."?  That should have been a clue that this was 1) about formal, not everyday, usage and 2) tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In modern use in [American English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=madam%2Cma+%27+am&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3), the term *ma'am* has gained quite a bit more use than *madam*:

> http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=madam%2Cma%20%27%20am&corpus=5&smoothing=3&year_start=1950&year_end=2008

In modern use in [British English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=madam%2Cma+%27+am&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3), *madam* is slightly more popular than *ma'am*:

> http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=madam%2Cma%20%27%20am&corpus=6&smoothing=3&year_start=1950&year_end=2008

As a native American English speaker, *madam* seems a bit archaic but does not necessarily connote a tie with a brothel unless you refer to someone as *a madam*. For example, the Oxford English dictionary provides the following example for *madam* of a brothel:

> 1959    N. Mailer Advts. for Myself (1961) 279   A rather remarkable woman who had been the madam of a whorehouse.

But as a form of address, it is used differently:

> 1956    N. Algren Walk on Wild Side ii. 122   It's not a pot, Madam. And it's strictly not for sale.

The typical terms I've heard are *miss* for younger females and *ma'am* for older ones. You could potentially refer to someone as *madam* or *ma'am* in either spoken or written communication. In *formal* writing, for example to someone whose name you do not know, use *madam* in both cases. For [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madam#Use_as_a_form_of_address):

> When addressing a letter to the holder of a particular position without knowing the name or gender of the addressee, it is common to write “Dear Sir or Madam,” (or in the United States, “Dear Sir or Madam:”

This holds in both American and British English.

In less formal writing or speech, I would suggest using whichever term is more popular for the community you are in--*ma'am* in American English, and *madam* in British English. In both, *madam* will seem a bit more formal.

Comment: Use 'miss' on enough women, and one of them will eventually complain you're being pert. Use 'madam' on enough women, and one will eventually take umbrage at your implying she is of advanced years. One is best advised to avoid that whole snake pit and refer to everyone, male and female alike, as 'sugar'.

Comment: @jela your comment is like the canonical definition of *punchline*

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen **ma'am** as a *written* form of address. Can anyone come up with credible examples?

Comment: Here is one credible [example (pdf)](http://www.mdanderson.org/how-you-can-help/other-ways-to-help/mobile-mammography/request-the-van/mammo-ptletter.pdf).

Comment: +1 - "*Dear Sir or Madam*, will you read my book? It took me years to write, will you take a look?"

Comment: @DKrueger. I was willing to have a look at your example, but it seems that the link is no longer valid. Could you supply a new one? Or at least clarify what it led to?

Comment: @simchona, Images down....

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe, just once, someone will call me "Sir" without adding, "You're
>   making a scene."
>   -- Homer Simpson

"Madam" as a noun certainly means "brothel keeper" in the US but I don't think that has stained its use as an honorific. I don't know why not; certainly no one whose job involves hooking things (like fish) or stripping things (like furniture) would be willing to describe that job as "hooking" or "stripping".

However, in the US, the honorific "Madam" is associated with a level of formality so great that anyone thus addressed will likely believe that she is being mocked (and usually, she'll be right).

In several Asian countries, the English word "hostess" is used to mean "madam" (in the improper sense); I've seen more than one party thrown in the US by new arrivals from the East almost go very very wrong when an American guest complimented the hostess using that word.

Comment: Is that "hostess" to mean...which meaning of "madam" in the East?

Comment: I'll never be able to watch commercials for Hostess Twinkies and Cupcakes the same way.

Comment: @Mitch, the meaning that would most upset a women who just meant to throw a party.

Comment: @Malvolio: ok, but does 'hostess' then mean brothel manager or just plain 'rostitute, or some other specific meaning?

Comment: @Mitch -- I'm not going to ask why exactly you need to know.  I'm not any sort of expert myself, but it seemed to me that in the US, the "madam" has a purely executive role while the Korean "room-salon" hostess is what you might call a hands-on manager.  More specific than that, you'll have to investigate for yourself.  Report back.

Comment: @Malvolio: Your edit clarifies: '"madam" (in the improper sense)' mentioned in the post

Comment: To appeal to you roots, you might interested to learn that the Italian equivalent, "madama", is used as a jargon word to refer to the police (I suppose as "fuzz" is in AE), that Palazzo Madama is the seat of the Italian Senate, and that yes, it could be referred to a brothel keeper, but consider that a law was passed in February 1958 to close brothels in Italy, so it is certainly old usage.

Comment: “Madam” is a female form a address, and precedes the full title when used in the vocative, just as “Mister” does for the male.  So Madam President, Madam Secretary, etc.

Comment: @Paola -- "fuzz"? I don't think that's been popular in American English since about 1958 either.  Nowadays, most of the really evocative words for police -- "fuzz", "pigs", "heat" -- are gone, replaced by just "cops" (which is utterly inoffensive), "po-po" (the use of which makes you sound like an idiot), and "the five-oh" (the use of which means you actually *are* an idiot).

Comment: Ooops, I've given myself (and my age range...) away! I learnt about this term when reading McBain's crime stories, and surely he started writing SOME time ago. However, I didn't know that "heat" could be used as a synonym for "police", which throws extra light on the title of one of his works. Please, don't tell me that also "dough" for "money" has fallen out of use!

Comment: @Paola -- McBain's *Heat* was published in 1981, by which time the meaning had broaden from *a policeman* ("The heat came around the corner.") to *unwanted official attention* generally ("We are getting heat from the home office.")  "Dough" is not quite as obsolete but it lacks a certain... currency (sorry).  The fossilized phrase "a lot of dough" is still around but I can't remember the last time I heard "dough" by itself.  You know what word for money came and went?  "Cheddar".

Comment: How funny! In Italian a term which is (I think) still used to indicate "money" is *grana*, which also indicates cheese similar to parmesan (I'd say that the major difference between them, apart from the production area, is that *grana* is less matured, so that it's more frequently eaten as it is instead of being grated). In any case, thanks for the information. I guess I could easily get used to resorting to your expertise when in doubt...

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be more a case of register. "Madam" is the female equivalent for "Sir." It's pretty much at the apex of formality.

"Ma'am," on the other hand, is more akin to "Mister" for men. A median level of decorum. Only context for "Madam" would risk confusion with the brothel-keeper. For example: When I've been lucky enough to dine at 4-star restaurants, women in the party are usually addressed as "Madam" by the waitstaff, and no offense is taken.

Comment: Interesting.  How does the use of "sir" and "ma'am" in the military compare to civilian use?

Comment: One presumes military lingo accords with tradition and obeys it's own trajectory, which occasionally intersects with civilian argot.

Comment: Compare “Mister President” with “Madam Secretary” when addressing the Clintons.

Answer (score 2):

Ngrams only show the usage in literature - which can be a bit selective.

Ma'am is used where you would use 'sir',for senior officer ranks, in the British police and armed forces.

Not sure what you would call a knighted owner of a brothel in BE - possibly "Madam ma'am" ?

Comment: Perhaps "Mdm Madam"?

Answer (score 2):

As a youngish Australian woman I take offence at *ma'am* — which sounds brusque, overly Americanised and inappropriate given my age — but never at *madam*, which to my ears sounds very polite and appropriate. Personally I would never use *ma'am*.

Comment: If you take offence when none is given and when indeed people are trying their best to be polite to you, then you are just setting yourself up for trouble. Why would you do that?

Comment: tchrist -- because words have meaning and different couintries are totally different countries.  There are things you can very easily say in Australia that would be unimaginable in certain other countries.

Answer (score -2):

Madam can refer to feminine side of a woman with affection. For example, "No, Madam, this is not the way one should take a screw driver;" plumber noted.

Comment: You could equally do that with *ma'am*