# Respectful alternative to "Madam"

Tags: single-word-requests, politeness

*Madam* is the word to call a woman with respect. ( Though of course it has other meanings, too). Are there any other words used to call a woman with respect?

Comment: "Madam" is only vulgar if you call someone *a* madam. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40905/madam-vs-maam/40909#40909) for some discussion.

Comment: Have you tried looking up synonyms in a thesaurus or dictionary?

Comment: _[Madam vs. Ma'am](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40905/5822)_

Comment: In general, the use of a formal term of respect carries a high risk of being seen as sarcastic in any circumstances where that level of formality isn't more-or-less demanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's *dame*, *ma'am*, *lady*, or *noblewoman*.  Unfortunately, most of these are reserved titles for royalty.  The one I find the most commonly used is *ma'am* (which is short for *madam*), although this too is a term used in Britain to address the queen or a royal princess according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ma%27am).

Comment: Dame, like madam, isn't always respectful.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent it also depends upon the context. @Bill provides helpful examples pertaining to royalty.

You can also use *Miss*, *Ms*, *Mrs.* suffixed by first or last name depending upon her position relative to the speaker.

[This](http://www.myuniversalfacts.com/2007/03/form-of-address-name-titles.html) link may help.

Answer (score -1):

Milady. Which is another term for "My lady." Milady shows respect and is less uptight as "madam." It can be used for royalty or just as a nice way to show appreciation and/or authority. It could be used as both in a way.